# Python matching a real/float number with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm not the best at re.

Can anyone tell me if this pattern will work to return a single occurrence of a whole or decimal number before the occurrence of the literal,"each"?  The number and the string each will be separated by a single space.

```
for each in parsed:
            if measure_string.find(each)>-1:
                r = re.compile("([0-9]\.?[0-9]?) "+each)
                b = re.match(r,measure_string)
                if b:
                    return b, each
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You should include example input & output.

Comment: Some input, expect output sample will help to clear you question

Comment: OP's asking what the regex will match, presumably. "What does this do?" kind of thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[0-9]\.?[0-9]?
```

The first [0-9] will match once occurrence of a digit.
The .? will match 0-1 periods
[0-9]? will match 0-1 digits.

So, your regex will parse 1, 11, 1.1, but not 1.11 or 11.1

If you want to parse all of the above, I suggest the following.

```
([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(?:\s)
```

[0-9]+ - Match 1 or more digits
\. - Match 1 period
[0-9]*? - Match all remaining digits.
()? - Enter this regex 0 or 1 times.

Anything within parenthesis will be captured. If you see a regex enclosed in (?:...) it is a NON-capturing regex. BUT if that (?...) is enclosed in a (...), it will be captured by the (...) regex... it's kind of messy. But the above should work to capture only the number and not the space.

Comment: What about `1.00000e-05`?

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that. If he needs it, I could add it to the answer pretty easily. If it's in his sample input/output, I'll fix the solution

Comment: Yeah I forgot about extra digits.  Thanks I think that works nicely

Comment: Does this match `.5` and `5.`?

Comment: @Hyperboreus, I explicitly wrote it to not handle either of those. Those numbers aren't correctly formatted.

Comment: @JustinDanielson Just out of curiosity, why is `.5` not correctly formatted? According to which standard?

Comment: Change the first + to a *, and it will handle the. .5 case.

Comment: @JustinDanielson If I change the first + to *, it also parses the empty string.

Comment: On my phone, but this should work. ((?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)(?:\s)  Hopefully if OP has decimals like this he'll let us know in the post, otherwise all this back and forth has been in vein.

Answer (score 3):

There is a more precise regexp of the real numbers:

`"^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$"`

And some check for this regexp:

```
import re
realnum=re.compile("^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$")

["yes" if realnum.match(test) else "no" for test in ["12", "+12", "-12", "-3.14", ".314e1", "+.01e-12", "+22.134E+2"]]
['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']

["yes" if realnum.match(test) else "no" for test in ["..12", "+-12", "-12.", "-3.14p", ".314e1.9", "+. 01e-12", "+22.134E"]]
['no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no']
```

I have added `[eE]` option according to Joonho's comment.

Comment: This is perfect but I want to add 'E' also. So, 'e' can be replaced by '[eE]'.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
\b(([1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]\.[0-9]+)\b
```

to match reals and

```
\b(([1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9])\b
```

to match simple.

nice place to test regexes: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
import re
def parse(measure_string,each):
    r = re.compile(r"\d+(\.\d*)?(?=\s"+each+")")
    b = re.match(r, measure_string)
    if(b):
        return b.group(0)
```

we are using a positive look ahead with ?= in order to match the float only if it's followed by whitespace and the string `each`, but to not include that whitespace and `each` in the match.
We then return the matched string with `MatchObject.group(0)` as per the [ref](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject).

Comment: In Python you could usually use raw string notation (and possibly string formatting) instead: `r"\d+(\.\d*)?(?=\s{})".format(each)`

Comment: there. added raw string notation.