# Find specific values in a txt file and adding them up with python

Tags: python, parsing, find, txt

I have a txt file which looks like that:

```
[Chapter.Title1]
Irrevelent=90 B
Volt=0.10 ienl
Watt=2 W 
Ampere=3 A 
Irrevelent=91 C

[Chapter.Title2]
Irrevelent=999
Irrevelent=999
    
[Chapter.Title3]
Irrevelent=92 B
Volt=0.20 ienl
Watt=5 W 
Ampere=6 A 
Irrevelent=93 C
```

What I want is that it catches "Title1" and the values "0,1", "2" and "3". Then adds them up (which would be 5.1).

I don't care about the lines with "irrevelent" at the beginning.

And then the same with the third block. Catching "Title3" and adding "0.2", "5" and "6".

The second block with "Title2" does not contain "Volt", Watt" and "Ampere" and is therefore not relevant.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Thank you and cheers

Comment: Try this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reading-ini-configuration-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to get the values and the titles in lists, then use them.

```
txt = """[Chapter.Title1]
Irrevelent=90 B
Volt=1 V
Watt=2 W 
Ampere=3 A 
Irrevelent=91 C

[Chapter.Title2]
Irrevelent=92 B
Volt=4 V
Watt=5 W 
Ampere=6 A 
Irrevelent=93 C"""
#that's just the text


import re

rx1=r'Chapter.(.*?)\]'
rxv1=r'Volt=(\d+)'
rxv2=r'Watt=(\d+)'
rxv3=r'Ampere=(\d+)'
res1 = re.findall(rx1, txt)
resv1 = re.findall(rxv1, txt)
resv2 = re.findall(rxv2, txt)
resv3 = re.findall(rxv3, txt)

print(res1)
print(resv1)
print(resv2)
print(resv3)
```

Here you get the titles and the interesting values you want :

```
['Title1', 'Title2']
['1', '4']
['2', '5']
['3', '6']
```

You can then use them as you want, for example :

```
for title_index in range(len(res1)):
  print(res1[title_index])
  value=int(resv1[title_index])+int(resv2[title_index])+int(resv3[title_index])  
  #use float() instead of int() if you have non integer values
  print("the value is:", value)
```

You get :

```
Title1
the value is: 6
Title2
the value is: 15
```

Or you can store them in a dictionary or an other structure, for example :

```
#dict(zip(keys, values)) 
data= dict(zip(res1, [int(resv1[i])+int(resv2[i])+int(resv3[i]) for i in range(len(res1))] ))

print(data)
```

You get :

```
{'Title1': 6, 'Title2': 15}
```

#### Edit : added opening of the file

```
import re

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    txt = file.read()


rx1=r'Chapter.(.*?)\]'
rxv1=r'Volt=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)'
rxv2=r'Watt=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)'
rxv3=r'Ampere=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)'
res1 = re.findall(rx1, txt)
resv1 = re.findall(rxv1, txt)
resv2 = re.findall(rxv2, txt)
resv3 = re.findall(rxv3, txt)

data= dict(zip(res1, [float(resv1[i])+float(resv2[i])+float(resv3[i]) for i in range(len(res1))] ))

print(data)
```

#### Edit 2 : ignoring missing values

```
import re

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    txt = file.read()
  
#divide the text into parts starting with "chapter"
substr = "Chapter"
chunks_idex = [_.start() for _ in re.finditer(substr, txt)]
chunks = [txt[chunks_idex[i]:chunks_idex[i+1]-1] for i in range(len(chunks_idex)-1)]
chunks.append(txt[chunks_idex[-1]:]) #add the last chunk
#print(chunks)

keys=[]
values=[]
rx1=r'Chapter.(.*?)\]'
rxv1=r'Volt=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)'
rxv2=r'Watt=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)'
rxv3=r'Ampere=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)'

for chunk in chunks:

  res1 = re.findall(rx1, chunk)
  resv1 = re.findall(rxv1, chunk)
  resv2 = re.findall(rxv2, chunk)
  resv3 = re.findall(rxv3, chunk)
  # check if we can find all of them by checking if the lists are not empty
  if res1 and resv1 and resv2 and resv3 :
    keys.append(res1[0])
    values.append(float(resv1[0])+float(resv2[0])+float(resv3[0]))

data= dict(zip(keys, values ))
print(data)
```

Comment: The last "You get:" looks perfect! That is what I need. Unfortunately, I am struggling to implement that including opening the file. Could you please send the whole code?

Comment: @GeSie check the last edit, 'filename.txt' is the name of your text file

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot! But now it seems I simplified the txt file example for you guys too much. The real file contains a values in this form: "0.xx" or "0.x". Your code only use the first number which is a "0". And I don't know if that's a problem but after the value there are sometimes up to four characters as the unit which I also don't need.

Comment: @GeSie it's just about changing the regex to what suits you. I changed it to `([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)` so now it can capture floats too (See if that's enough or not). You might need to change it if there are other exceptions, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20291683/14580023) or [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) in general.

Comment: now I recognized that not under every [Chapter.TitleX] there are my requested values. Is it somehow possible to ignore those blocks that do not contain the values "Volt", "Watt", "Ampere"?

Comment: @GeSie that's kind of a different question. See edit 2. I divided the text into chunks , then if all the values exist in a chunk we take them, otherwise we dont and we continue to the next chunk.

Comment: @GeSie I've just seen all these comments and note that the question has effectively changed. Please update the original question to indicate what you really have / want

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do this, reading line by line, if the input file is predictable enough.

In the example I just print out the titles and the values; you can of course process them however you want.

```
f = open('file.dat','r')

for line in f.readlines():

    ## Catch the title of the line:
    if '[Chapter' in line:
        print(line[9:-2])

    ## catch the values of Volt, Watt, Amere parameters
    elif line[:4] in ['Volt','Watt','Ampe']:
        value = line[line.index('=')+1:line.index(' ')]
        print(value)

    ## if line is "Irrelevant", or blank, do nothing

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here's one:

```
d = dict()
V = {'Volt', 'Watt', 'Ampere'}
with open('chapter.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    key = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('[Chapter'):
            d[key := line.strip()] = 0
        elif key and len(t := line.split('=')) > 1 and t[0] in V:
            d[key] += float(t[1].split()[0])

for k, v in d.items():
    if v > 0:
        print(f'Total for {k} = {v}')
```

**Output:**

```
Total for [Chapter.Title1] = 6
Total for [Chapter.Title2] = 15
```